# Variables common to all individuals in a panel

Tags: regression, panel-data, econometrics, application, research-design

I have been tasked with evaluating the efficiency of different marketing tools for a microfinance bank. 
I have a panel of seven individuals (seven districts of Tajikistan) over 17 months.

Dependent variable is the number of new clients, independent variables are the levels of spending in each marketing instrument (leaflets, tv, billboards...) (in log).
But some of the spending is national. Hence, I have decided to separate the spending in two categories (e.g. local tv and national tv), and to attribute the national values to each of the observations of my panel (i.e. all of the cities will have the same value for their variable "national tv ads" in December).

I'll interpret the coefficients as the local effect of national spending.
The way I see it, the coefficients obtained will be based only on the variability of the dependent variable, but that should still give me a proper estimate.

Do you see any flaws in that way of proceeding?

I have run a regression with fixed effects and clustered errors, in Stata.

Comment: If you want the effect of "national spending" to vary across local branch. You may consider panel model with random slope. Think about $y_{it} = x_{it}'\alpha + s_{t}b_{i} + c_{i} + u_{it}$. $b_{i}$ is the partial effect of spending for branch $i$. Under additional exogeneity condition (e.g. $b_{i}$ is mean independent of $(x_{it}, s_{t})$), you can still use FE estimator to estimate a model like $y_{it} = x_{it}'\alpha + s_{t}\beta + c_{i} + v_{it}$, but FE will converge to $E(b_{i})$. So $\beta$ is the average, not branch-specific, partial effect of spending.